# How to set VW and VH value to select option

Tags: css, responsive-design

Could someone tell me how to replace responsive bootstrap with VW and VH value for select option?

I'm trying to recreate as mentioned [here](https://www.elegantthemes.com/blog/divi-resources/how-to-use-vw-and-vh-length-units-to-design-a-responsive-contact-form-in-divi). but I don't understand its basic usage.

I need my select option to be behave like in that link.

here is my normal bootstrap [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/SathyaHere/cmq8ph6g/9/) . But I don't want to use bootstrap

[updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/SathyaHere/cmq8ph6g/12/)

my very minimal HTML structure

```
<select class="form-control" id="gender1">
    <option>Male</option>
    <option>Female</option>
</select>
```

**Note**: what i actually need is, select option should behave when resize according to DIV. I've given `WIDTH` and `HEIGHT` in `VW` for `DIV`

Thanks to all,

Comment: You want to have strange staggered form element widths? Or are you asking how to have a select element that fits inside a box, has some padding around it and is responsive?

Comment: JHeth i'm already working some STRANGE requirements, in the design documents. have been mentioned HEIGHT and WIDTH of div in WV. so if re-size the browser its working okay for DIV alone. but there is no VW values for elements inside DIV. so its behaving strange.

Comment: As an interesting aside, there are now (apparently) 24 different gender labels that people should be offered, rather than simple binary Male or Female

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
select{
  display: block;
  width: 100%; /* define the size of the width */
  max-width: 100vw; /* the width equal to screen larger */
}
```

```html
<label for="gender1">I'm label</label>   
<select id="gender1">
  <option>Male</option>
  <option>Female</option>
</select>
```

Hello , here my code. You just need to modify the value of select width to change the size of options. I hope this will help you !

Comment: Yes exactly. But how to set HEIGHT for that? i set it to 100vw but its going endless

Comment: The height is defined by browser. Sometimes , you can't change this value (for firefox for exemple)